# Discuss the validity of the procedure of Riccati equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation (Riccati)
$$x'=a(t)x^2 + b(t)x + c(t),\tag1$$
where $a(t), b(t),$ and $c(t)$ are continuous real functions on a given interval $(\alpha, \beta)$.

- Show that, generally, there exist solutions of the Riccati equation that are not defined on the whole interval $(\alpha, \beta)$. More precisely, such solutions tend to $\pm \infty$, as $t \to T \in (\alpha, \beta)$. Is $T$ independent of the solution?
- Assume that we know a solution $x=x_0(t)$ of the Riccati equation and show that by changing the unknown function by means of the formula $x=x_0(t)+\frac{1}{y}$, we find a linear differential equation in $y$. Discuss the validity of the preceding procedure in reducing a Riccati equation to a linear one.

---

This is how far I can get.

Assuming that we have the particular solution of $x'$, say $x=x_0(t)$. Now, we were looking for the solution of $x'$ which in the form
$$x=x_0(t)+\frac{1}{y(t)},$$
where $y(t)$ is an another function of $t$. Thus, $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dx_0(t)}{dt}-\frac{1}{y^2} \frac{dy}{dt}.\tag2$$
Evaluating $x=x_0(t)$ from Riccati equation, we have $$\frac{dx_0(t)}{dt} = a(t)x_0^2(t)+b(t)x_0(t)+c(t)\tag3$$.
Thus, (for simplicity, we will omit using "$(t)$" in $x$ and $y$)
\begin{align}
a(t)x^2 + b(t)x + c(t)&=\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dx_0}{dt}-\frac{1}{y^2} \frac{dy}{dt}  \tag{4a}\\
a(t)(x_0+\frac{1}{y})^2 + b(t)(x_0+\frac{1}{y}) + c(t)&=a(t)x_0^2+b(t)x_0+c(t)-\frac{1}{y^2}\frac{dy}{dt}  \tag{4b}\\
&\vdots&\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=(2a(t)+b(t))y=-a(t)  \tag{4c}.
\end{align}
Hence, the solution for $\frac{dy}{dt}$ is,
$$y(t)=\frac{\int -a(t) e^{\int (2a(t)+b(t)) dt}dt}{e^{\int (2a(t)+b(t)) dt}}.  \tag5$$
So,$$x=x_0(t)+\frac{e^{\int (2a(t)+b(t)) dt}}{\int -a(t) e^{\int (2a(t)+b(t)) dt}dt}.  \tag6$$

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you are asking.

Comment: This appears to be a copy-paste of a problem from somewhere. The [guidelines for a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) suggest attributing where you got the problem from, and has [further advice for improving "no-clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Answer (score 1):

I do not see how you expanded the square, the resulting formula (4c) has symbol errors or some other transmission defect. I get
$$
\color{blue}{x_0'}-y^{-2}y'=a(\color{blue}{x_0^2}+2x_0y^{-1}+y^{-2})+b(\color{blue}{x_0}+y^{-1})+\color{blue}{c}\\
\implies
-y'=a(2x_0y+1)+by=(2ax_0+b)y+a
$$
The solution formula then after that seems to be again correct up to the omission of a $x_0$ factor. But you could have stopped at obtaining the linear first-order DE, exactly because it has a well-known solution formula.

As you can set an initial condition for $y$ to be zero at any point $T$ in the interval $(α,β)$, you also get an answer for the first question which is the "worst case" of the described possibilities.

Comment: from $x'=ax^2+bx+c$, substitute $x=x_0$, we get $x_0'=ax_0^2+bx_0+c$.

Comment: Yes, these are the blue terms that cancel in the first equation.

Comment: can you tell me the validity of this process?

Comment: Can you tell me what "validity" means? If you care to note the possibilities for division-by-zero, then all these transformations are equivalencies, so they keep the number and kind of solutions the same.