# Existence of solutions of the Riccati Equation that are not define on the interval $(\alpha,\beta)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation (Riccati)
$$x'=a(t)x^2+b(t)x+c(t),$$
where $a(t),b(t)$, and $c(t)$ are continuous real functions on a given interval $(α,β)$.

Show that, generally, there exist solutions of the Riccati equation that are not defined on the whole interval $(α,β)$. More precisely, such solutions tend to $±∞$, as $t→T\in (α,β)$. Is $T$ independent of the solution?

This problem is from Principle of Differential and Integral Equations by C.Corduneanu and related to this problem  [THIS PROBLEM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3830674/discuss-the-validity-of-the-procedure-of-riccati-equation)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $y=\frac1x$, then it has an equation
$$
-y'=y^2(ax^2+bx+c)=a+by+cy^2.
$$
Select some $T\in(α,β)$ with $a(T)\ne 0$. Now consider a solution of this equation with $y(T)=0$. On some interval around $T$ this solution is non-zero. $x=\frac1y$ is then a (local) solution of the original equation with a pole at $t=T$.

This should be sufficient to answer the question.